# slapd: result.c:813: slap_send_ldap_result: Assertion `!((rs->sr_err)<0)' failed

Tags: ssl, configuration, openldap

LTB-Project.org or OpenLDAP.org developers, please help:

I am still having problems with adding (via .ldif file) the following LDIF file contents of `/tmp/LDAP-CONFIG-TLS.ldif`:

```
dn:                       cn=config<br>
changetype:               modify<br>
add:                      olcTLSCipherSuite<br> 
olcTLSCipherSuite:        TLSv1+RSA:\!EXP:\!MD5:\!NULL   #(<- not sure if that argument is valid for that CipherSuite selection either)
```

I use the following ldapmodify command:

```
ldapmodify    -x     -D "cn=admin,cn=config" -W  -f /tmp/LDAP-CONFIG-TLS.ldif
```

Because I have debugging turned up `(to -d 32768)`, the results now look like:

```
modifying entry "cn=config"
52e68423 connection_input:  conn=1000 deferring operation: binding<p>
slapd: result.c:813:  slap_send_ldap_result: Assertion `!((rs->sr_err)<0)' failed. 
ldap_result:  Can't contact LDAP server  (-1)
```

I saw [a thread on openldap.org that has the exact same error](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-bugs/201308/msg00066.html).  I can see that Howard Chu from Symas fixed the problem for Symas, did LTB Project fix this problem?  I cannot find any threads via websearch for this issue.

What do I need to do in order to get my LDAP running with TLS?

Comment: This question would likely have a better chance in serverfault.com, specifically http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/openldap

Answer (score 0):

your must re-Import your LDIF with the new schema and you will not get again this error. When you modify a new attrs on your schema like matchingrule or another thing, the changement is available for the new add. so you need to reimport your database.